# ARIMA(1,1,1) equation based on R output

Tags: r, time-series, arima

[image]

For the above output, what would my equation look like given these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are taking the first difference you have $Y_t=X_t-X_{t-1}$.  Then you have $Y_t = -0.711895 Y_{t-1} + e_t -0.503328 e_{t-1}$ where the $e_t$s are independent identically distributed with mean zero and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Also the ar1 and ma1 parameters are (highly) statistically different from zero. You see this by noting that $\text{Pr}(>|z|)$ is extremely small in each case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I had it as Y(t)= -0.711895 Y(t-1) + e(t)+0.503328 e(t-1) , I always though it was e(t)--.

Comment: But did you realize that the original series X(t)  is not Y(t)?  Note Y(t)=X(t)-X(t-1). This would be in addition to the fact that the moving average term has a - sign rather than a +.

Comment: Do you want to accept my answer and/or vote for it?

Comment: @MichaelChernick, a user with reputation 1 cannot vote.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I believe that the arima.fit output reports the ma coefficients in the negative as compared to the classical  Box-Jenkins notation